# Calculating field from variable using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, field-calculator

using python editor in QGIS, I want to update a field based on a variable calculated previously in my script (`x` for this example).
I have used the code with success when using an expression based on other fields
e.g:

`expression = QgsExpression("field1||'_'||field2")`

but I can't get it to work when the expression is based on a variable, not a field.

```
x = 5 
id_new_col= layer.dataProvider().fieldNameIndex("field") 
expression = QgsExpression("x") 
context = QgsExpressionContext() 
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer)) 
for f in layer.getFeatures():
        with edit(layer):
            context.setFeature(f)
            f['field'] = expression.evaluate(context)
            layer.updateFeature(f)
```

This results in an empty field.

How can I call the variable into the field calculator expression?

Comment: Where do you use this script, in "Function Editor" or "Python Editor"?  Please add the whole script. It is not clear what `layer` is. It is a vector layer, of course. But where does it come from?

Comment: And, `x` in `x = 5` and `x` in `QgsExpression("x") ` are not related., The former is a python variable, the latter indicates a field in the layer, I guess.